# Azure piplines artifacts strange additional folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I pubished my artifacts with this config:

```
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: "Copy files to $(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: ${{ parameters['sourceFolder'] }}
      contents: ${{ parameters['contents'] }}
      targetFolder: "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
  - ${{ if parameters.archiveType }}:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: Archive files
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)"
        archiveType: ${{ parameters['archiveType'] }}
        tarCompression: none
        archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters['archiveName'] }}.zip"
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      artifactName: ${{ parameters['artifactName'] }}
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

The problem is that there is additional folder named `xoac`. I don't know why this folder is created and how to get name of this folder.
Here is a screenshot present what I mean:
[image]

Then I want to publish them on github:

```
      - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
        inputs:
          artifactName: ${{ parameters['artifactName'] }}
      - bash: |
          MY_TAG="$(Build.SourceBranch)"
          MY_TAG=${MY_TAG#refs/tags/}
          echo $MY_TAG
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.my_tag]$MY_TAG"
          DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=build.date]$DATE"
        displayName: "Create date and tag variables"

      - task: GitHubRelease@0
        displayName: "GithubRelease@0 '$(build.my_tag) - $(build.date)'"
        inputs:
            gitHubConnection: PipelinesTemplates
            tagSource: manual
            title: '$(build.my_tag) - $(build.date)'
            tag: '$(build.my_tag)'
            assetUploadMode: ${{ parameters['assetUploadMode'] }}
            action: ${{ parameters['action'] }}
            assets: "${{parameters['artifactName']}}/*"  # target is the same what artifactName in download step
            repositoryName: ${{ parameters['repositoryName'] }}
            isPreRelease: true
```

And `GitHubRelease@0` task print this note:

> Release notes file: /home/vsts/work/1/s is a directory and not a file.

How to config task `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` to not create additional `xaoc` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to config task PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to not create additional xaoc folder?

Since I do not have your parameters `sourceFolder` `archiveType` `archiveName` and the folder structure, I could not give you a accurate answer for this issue. But I would like provide some troubleshootings here.

First, for the task `PublishBuildArtifacts`:

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      artifactName: ${{ parameters['artifactName'] }}
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

As you can see you are publish the files from the default folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` to the targetPath `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, which make no sense.

I suppose you are publish the build artifacts to the Azure pipeline, so it should be like:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ${{ parameters['artifactName'] }}'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Second, as we know, the default path for the argument `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` should be simple value, like: `d:\a\1\a`. So, the additional folder named `xoac` should not comes from the argument `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. In other words, this issue may not comes from the task `PublishBuildArtifacts@1`.

Besides, since the ArchiveFiles task generate the `.zip` file by:

`archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters['archiveName'] }}.zip"`

The additional folder named xoac may comes from the `archiveName` in the ArchiveFiles task. You can check the log of this task or you can run your pipeline on the private agent to check if those files under the `xaoc` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for long response. It looks like you are right. It comes from the default name archive witch is `$(Build.Repository.Name)`. I will test this on weekend and I will let you know. If you wanna look for source code you can find it here: https://github.com/xoac/rust-azure-pipelines/tree/v0.1.0-alpha.2